# Qt not recognising declared class

Tags: qt, compiler-errors

I use Qt 4.6.3 to write application for FriendlyARM. I am trying to pass 2 pointers (pointing to classes `axesParam1` and `mainWin`) to current class `localTime` but get these errors :

```
localtime.h:17: error: 'axesParam1' has not been declared
localtime.h:18: error: 'mainWin' has not been declared
localtime.h:26: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'axesParam1' with no type
localtime.h:26: error: expected ';' before '*' token
localtime.h:27: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'mainWin' with no type
localtime.h:27: error: expected ';' before '*' token
In file included from trackinputstatus.h:5,
from trackinput.h:5,
from mainwin.h:8,
from geoparam.h:5,
from axesparam3.h:5,
from axesparam2.h:5,
from axesparam1.h:5,
from main.cpp:14:
trackparamstatus.h:16: error: 'mainWin' has not been declared
trackparamstatus.h:24: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'mainWin' with no type
trackparamstatus.h:24: error: expected ';' before '*' token
main.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
main.cpp:52: error: no matching function for call to 'localTime::setChildren(axesParam1*)'
localtime.h:17: note: candidates are: void localTime::setChildren(int*)
main.cpp:61: error: no matching function for call to 'localTime::setHome(mainWin*)'
localtime.h:18: note: candidates are: void localTime::setHome(int*)
main.cpp:62: error: no matching function for call to 'trackParamStatus::setHome(mainWin*)'
trackparamstatus.h:16: note: candidates are: void trackParamStatus::setHome(int*)
```

I did not declared `setChildern` to accept `int*` as an argument so why is it insisting on `int*`?

I have included the header file `localtime.h`

```
#ifndef LOCALTIME_H
#define LOCALTIME_H

#include  <QWidget>
#include "axesparam1.h"
#include "mainwin.h"

namespace Ui {
    class localTime;
}

class localTime : public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    localTime(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~localTime();
    void setChildren(axesParam1 *);
    void setHome(mainWin *);


protected:
    void changeEvent(QEvent *e);

private:
    Ui::localTime *ui;
    axesParam1 *P1;
    mainWin *w;

};

#endif // LOCALTIME_H
```

Comment: Are you including `localtime.h` in `axesparam1.h` or in `mainwin.h`?

Comment: @thuga I am using it in main.cpp. I thought that the header files declared (hence the classes declared) were restricted to a single cpp file when the cpp file isn't extended/implemented. Or am I missing something?

Comment: If `axesparam1.h` is including `localtime.h`, the declarations will be skipped due to the `#ifndef` line at the beginning of `.h` files. That is why I'm asking you to check if `axesparam1.h` is including `localtime.h`.

Comment: @thuga so what to do when I need the class in multiple classes?

Comment: You use forward declaration. You can remove the `axesparam1.h` and `mainwin.h` includes from your `localtime.h`, and forward declare those classes. Then you include those headers in your `localtime.cpp` file. [This should be a good read](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/10627/).

Answer (score 0):

You look too far down. Before you look at setChildern you should look into axesparam1 and/or mainwin.

> localtime.h:17: error: 'axesParam1' has not been declared
>   localtime.h:18: error: 'mainWin' has not been declared

You have some syntex error earlier. setChildern is only some follow-up error.